# Typescript interfaces don't do checking on method parameters?

Tags: typescript

```
interface optionsParameter { 
     url: string;

} 

function DEC(options: optionsParameter){ } 
DEC(2) //typescript check compilation error

let obj:any = {
   name: "Hello"
}

obj.DEC = function(options: optionsParameter){}

obj.DEC(1); // no compilation error thrown
```

I want the obj.DEC method to do type checking based on the specified interface but it does not.

It seems only regular function declarations or expressions work, not inside an object as a method.

Comment: I suspect your definition of `obj` is resulting in an "any" datatype, so any type checking on that object from then on is not performed.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a different code example exhibiting this behavior, since the one in your question doesn't actually compile; can you update your question to match it more closely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you defined `obj` as an empty object

```
let obj = {
}
```

the following line is not allowed

`obj.DEC = function(options: optionsParameter){}`

because you've already defined `obj` as an object with no properties. That's why the subsequent line isn't type-checking as you expect.

If, however, you define `obj` as an object with the `DEC` function, type checking will work as you expect:

```
let obj = {
    DEC: function(options: optionsParameter){}
}
```

Comment: paste your code into https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html to see

Comment: Nevermind, I see now. I would need to create an interface and apply the type to the variable assignment.